Firefox: Force external links to open in specific window
I have multiple Firefox windows open on different monitors - one main window where I do all my work, and one just for watching videos.
Whenever I am using a different application and I click on a link, that opens a new tab in whichever window was focused last. There are similar questions here for Chrome but none for Firefox.
The only thing I can think to do is create an AutoHotkey script that will focus the main window and then run firefox.exe to open the URL, then compile it and register it as the default browser. This seems like a nasty hack but right now it's my only option.

yeah this isn't actually about Firefox (or chrome) but how windows handles default associations for web urls. If firefox is your default browser the link will open in the last firefox window to get focus. the behavior is exactly the same for chrome if it is the default browser. Not entirely sure what you mean by "main window" (all firefox windows are created equal) but if you are talking about a screen/monitor, that doesn't have anything to do with it. its just whatever firefox window had focus last.

It absolutely is about Firefox. Just because Firefox and Chrome do the same thing doesn't mean it's not an issue. Firefox could absolutely have a checkbox in the menu that says "Open all external links in this window". Then, that window becomes the default. I don't know of an extension API that would let me do that, though.

If you would like to make a feature request for firefox, you can do so hear: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/file-bug-report-or-feature-request-mozilla . As it stands your question to the SU community doesn't actually contain a question. Perhaps the best bet is to add a question that can be answered.
